# Solving equations of motion for coupled oscillators

Tags: python, scipy

The question asks about a system with two masses each attached to two springs that looks like this:

|s s s s s M1 S S S S M2 s s s s|

The outer springs have a spring constant kb and the inner spring has a constant of ks. I wrote some code to find the normal modes for the system and I get that the frequency is 0.160 and I am pretty sure that is correct. However, when I try to solve the same problem using linear algebra, I get eigenvalues of -1.2 and -1.0. I also don't really understand how to write the code for this since my equations of motion don't fit into any examples of python code I have seen so far and I don't know how to make the matrix d^2/dt^2X to pass into the eigh() function. The equations of motion are:

d^2/dt^2 X = AX
where X is a vector and A is the matrix with masses and spring constants.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
from scipy import linalg as LA

A = np.array([[(-1/m1)*(kb+ks),(1/m1)*ks],[(1/m2)*ks,(-1/m2)*(kb+ks)]])
w,v = LA.eigh(A)
print(w)
print(v)
```

Comment: This differential equations page has a detailed analysis  including all the equations. for this and even an animation with sliders for the parameters. https://www.math24.net/mass-spring-system/

Answer (score 0):

Recast the 2nd order system as a system of 1st order ODEs (dx/dt = Cx) by adding the velocities of each mass as variables. Look at https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/CoupledSpringMassSystem.html. Regarding the eigenvalues / eigenvectors, you must consider those of the C matrix, not A. Then you directly get the modes.

For this, use the scipy.linalg.eig function, not eigh, because eigh only works with complex Hermitian (conjugate symmetric) or real symmetric matrices, which will not be the case here.

I've written a code for a similar system here:
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36357/system-of-second-order-odes-runge-kutta-4th-order/36358?noredirect=1#comment70848_36358